# Doubt in the proof of area theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

I was going through the proof of following version of area theorem, in which I have some doubts at the start of the proof.

Theorem: If f is analytic and one-one on open unit disc with $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)>0$, then area($f(\mathbb D)$), where $\mathbb D$ is domain which is open disc is given by $\pi \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n \mid a_n \mid ^2$.

Now they have started the proof with this equality. Say $f(\mathbb D)=D$, then 
area$(D)=\frac{1}{2i}\int_{\partial D}\bar w 
 dw$, by green's theorem which is ok to me. But why are we assuming here that $f(\mathbb D)=D$, is going to be bounded set, otherwise $\partial D$, won't make any sense na?

and immediately they gave following equality.

By applying change of variable we have,

$\frac{1}{2i}\int_{\partial D}\bar w 
 dw=\frac{1}{2i}\int_{\mathbb D}\bar {f(z)} 
 f'(z)dz$. Everything is ok here but I am not convinced how we can say that boundary of domain will get mapped to boundary of $D$. The remaining proof is fine to me. Just stuck on this two doubts for some time. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, the proof proceeds by taking $r\mathbb{D}$ for $0<r<1$ and that is mapped by $f$ into an analytic Jordan domain, for which the result holds by the usual computations and then we take the limit $r \to 1$ where we allow both sides in the limit to be infinite of course - that is part of the conclusion in the sense that if the area of the image is finite than the LHS series is finite and equal to it, while if the area is infinite, the LHS series is infinite too; that boundary goes to boundary is an easy topological fact given that $f$ is an open map (note that for $r\mathbb{D}$ we have a homeomorphism between the closed domains $\bar{r\mathbb{D}}$ and $\bar{f(r\mathbb{D})}$)

Comment: but f may not be even defined on $\partial D$. What to do in that case?

Comment: You do not need $f$ on the boundary of the unit disc, just on the boundary of smaller radius discs $\mathbb{rD}$ and then you let $r \to 1$. For the full unit disc, you can only say that if $z_n \to \partial \mathbb{D}$ and $f(z_n)$ has a limit $w$ then $w$ is on the boundary of $f(\mathbb{D})$.